# Finding a mistake in example $1.2.3$ in Analysis $1$ by Tao

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

After having just proved that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$ diverges for $x>1$, exercise $6.3.4$ asks to find the flaw in the following example given at the beginning of the book discussing why we need to study analysis.

Example $1.2.3$: Here is a slight variation of the previous example. Let $x$ be a real number, and let $L$ be the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n=L$$

Changing variables $n = m + 1$, we have $$L=\lim_{m+1\to\infty}x^{m+1}=\lim_{m+1\to\infty}xx^m=x\lim_{m+1\to\infty}x^m$$

But if $m+1\to\infty$, then $m\to \infty$, thus $$\lim_{m+1\to\infty}x^m=\lim_{m\to\infty}x^m=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=L$$

and thus $$xL=L$$

At this point we could cancel the $L’s$ and conclude that $x = 1$ for an
arbitrary real number $x$, which is absurd. But since we are already
aware of the division by zero problem, we could be a little smarter and
conclude instead that either $x = 1$, or $L = 0$. In particular we seem to
have shown that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0\space \text{for all $x$ $\ne$ $1$}$$

---

The following are what I think are the flaws in this example.

$1.$ The first thing is that we are not restricting $x$ in any way. If we were to restrict $0<x<1$, then we can prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$$

$2.$ Another flaw is that the sentence if $m+1\to \infty $, then $m\to \infty$ doesn't make any sense in this context. I get what he is trying to say, but so far in the book, nothing resembling the above sentence has been talked about except for in the context of sequences. If that is the case, then I would interpret the above sentence to mean that $$\lim_{m+1\to \infty}m=\infty$$ But then I am not sure how to interpret the $m+1$ here.

Are these the flaws or am I missing something here?

Comment: After reading your rebuttal comment to my answer, I double checked the Real Analysis theorem.  You are right and the analysis in my answer was flawed.  Therefore, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main flaw is assuming the limit $L$ exists and is a real number in the first place (for instance, for $x = - 1$, the sequences oscillates and admits no limit, and if $x > 1$, you know that the limit if $+\infty$).

Comment: Yeah that was my first guess. But then when proving that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n$ diverges for $x> 1$, the hint was to prove by contradiction. So I think that the flaw is something else. Because the assumption should lead to a contradiction but it really doesn’t.

Comment: It does! Assuming $x > 1$ and $L$ exists and is a real number you, obtain $L=0$, but obviously $L$ cannot be $0$ since $|x^n| > 1$ for every natural number $n$.

Comment: I was just confusing myself by thinking that the flaw might be something else. Thanks!